# Apply values to Dask dataframe mapping with function

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed

In the Dask code below I'm attempting to set a value of a dataframe field based on a logic in a function, `apply_masks`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as daskDataFrame

def apply_masks(df):
   if df['Age'] > 14:
       df['outcol'] = 6
   else:
       df['outcol'] = 5
   return df

data = [[1,100, 12, 6], [1,200, 18, 5], [1,170, 22, 4]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['outcol', 'Weight', 'Age', 'Height']) 
ddf = daskDataFrame.from_pandas(df, npartitions=100)
ddf = ddf.map_partitions(apply_masks)
print(ddf.compute())
```

Problem is that get an exception:

> ValueError: Metadata inference failed in `apply_masks`.
>
> You have supplied a custom function and Dask is unable to  determine
> the type of output that that function returns.
>
> To resolve this please provide a meta= keyword. The docstring of the
> Dask function you ran should have more information.
>
> Original error is below:
> ------------------------ ValueError('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().')

How to fix this?

Comment: `df['Age'] > 14` gives a series of bools Like `[True, False, True, True]` etc... were you trying to set outcol to `6` for all `Age > 14` and to `5` for all other Ages?

Comment: yes, that's the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html#pandas-dataframe-assign) + [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where):

```
def apply_masks(df):
    return df.assign(outcol=np.where(df['Age'] > 14, 6, 5))
```

Result:

```
   outcol  Weight  Age  Height
0       5     100   12       6
1       6     200   18       5
2       6     170   22       4
```

Comment: this works for the case when I have two possible values, 6 and 5, but I was looking for a generic approach. What if I have 100 possible values to assign to `outcol` based on `Age`?

Comment: I'd say you're probably looking for [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html#pandas-cut). However, since your question does not mention additional categories, or how they're assigned that's only a guess. If you update your question to include a some information for a few of those categories I can update my answer based on that.